# How to test a utility method that returns a new instance using Jupiter in Java?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit-jupiter

I have a something like this one:

```
class User {
    String name;
}

class Contacts {
    User getUser() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

I do it this way so that in my test I can mock the method like:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ContactsTest {
    @Spy
    private Contacts sut;

    @Mock
    private User user;

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        doReturn(user).when(sut).getUser();
    }

    @Test
    void testGetUser() {
        // verify(new User(), times(1));
        // verify(user, times(1));
    }
}
```

How could I test `testGetUser`?

The only two ideas I had which are commented above gave me these errors:

For the first one:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type User and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
```

For the second one

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since your unit under test is the `Contacts` class there is no need to `spy` on it and mock its behavior as this is the class you need to test. So, I would go ahead and remove that.

Now regarding your question, what you need to test is the actual outcome of the `getUser`, so the simplest of all tests would be to invoke the method on an instance of `Contacts` and assert that the returned result is a `non-null` instance of a `User` object.

If you really want to test that the constructor of the `User` class gets called, you will need to actually mock that call using either `PowerMock` (which is advise against and most likely does not even work with JUnit5) or use `mockito-inline`.

Once this is done you would be able to return a mocked `User` instance from the constructor call which you can then run assertions on.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation, the `non-null` instance actually solved it, I'll accept the answer once I'm allowed to